# CheckBoxFor resetting the model to null in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm iterating a list to set the values for multiple *Html.CheckBoxFor* controls, but after submitting the form, I get a null value for the model itself in the controller parameter. Should I replace *Html.CheckBoxFor* with *Html.HiddenFor* for instance, the whole model binding works and *FunctionViewModel* is passed to the controller properly.

**Model**

```
public class FunctionViewModel
{
    //... (this class is huge)
    public MeasuringViewModel MeasuringViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Classes used by the model**

```
public class MeasuringViewModel
{
   //... (this class is also huge)
   public List<BatchItem> BatchToCancel { get; set; }
}

public class BatchItem
{
    public bool IsCancel { get; set; }
    public VMeasuringService VMeasuringService { get; set; }

    public BatchItem(VMeasuringService vMeasuringService)
    {
        IsCancel = false;
        VMeasuringService = vMeasuringService;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CancelBatch(FunctionViewModel viewModel)
{
    // viewModel is null should I use CheckBoxFor

    return View();
}
```

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CancelBatch", "Services", FormMethod.Post, new { Area = "Functions", @id = "cancelForm" }))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.MeasuringViewModel.BatchToCancel.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MeasuringViewModel.BatchToCancel[i].IsCancel)
    }

    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" title="Post" alt="Post" value="Post" />
}
```

So, what's wrong with it?

Comment: You're not specifying `BatchToCancel` property anywhere in the viewmodel, is it has type of `List<BatchItem>` inside `MeasuringViewModel`?

Comment: Oh, that was an oversight by my part when I entered the code here. You see, the actual code is not in English, so I usually translate and simplify everything to give a minimal, thoroughly understandable example. Here I had `Batch` of type `List<BatchItem>` in `MeasuringViewModel` while I was calling `BatchToCancel` in the View, but Visual Studio itself wouldn't allow such nonsense. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get null because none of the control ids matching with your model properties, Check by Inspecting your html in browser that, is control ids generated by Razor are matching with your model properties?

secondly in this situation where you cannot give specific ids to your controls then you can get your control value in your controller action using FormCollection like given bellow:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CancelBatch(FormCollection fc)
{
    // viewModel is null should I use CheckBoxFor

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I actually do have matching properties, I edited the original post and you may  check my answer to Tetsuya Yamamoto's comment in there so you can  understand what happened. Regardless, I have tried getting that to work for three days until I gave up and now I am parsing the FormCollection in order to fetch the values I want. Your tip gave me that idea, I'll post a full answer once I have the time, thanks mate